# localhost refused to connect when importing wordpress to localhost, using wamp

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I am trying to deploy a local version of a live website on my localhost for a local environment. There is an error whereby "This site can't be reached. "" refused to connect.
We have tried the following:

- Changing the config for the siteurl and home changing the options for
  siteurl and home on the database directly
- Changing the database name
  to match the database in php/myadmin changing the virtualhost on
  httpd-vhosts.conf adding in the hosts in drivers/etc
- un-commenting the conf in httpd.conf
- changing the port to another port checking for other apps that could be listening to the same port
- including an inbound rules with the firewall for port 80
- checking the apache error logs

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: See if you can get a basic index.html to show up first

Comment: At the time it used to work, did you use http or https? How did you move site from live to local?

Comment: Do you see your db table on phpmyadmin ?

Comment: Seems like you threw the Kitchen sink at it. But most of the things you mention dont seem relevant. Can I suggest you start again, identify a problem and then ask for help with a solution. There is a very useful WordPress [help page on how to do this](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/)

Comment: @GBWDev the basic files like index.php are unable to show. Also tried creating a testconnection.php to test the connection to the database and it just returns to the localhost page

Comment: @Kubadev I am trying to deploy wordpress from a git repo onto my local environment. I see my db table on phpmyadmin. For some reason, even when I change the database name on wp-config, when I try to access the wp-admin, the name shown in the help is the old name. I tried using the copy from git again and apparently at first it says unable to connect to the database, but once I change the database to the one in wp-config, the error for refused to connect appears.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to do this :

1. Make a clean install of Wordpress on your localhost then check if it works.
2. Install a plugin on your live website who will duplicate your website. (You can see [here](https://winningwp.com/best-plugins-to-copy-clone-duplicate-a-wordpress-site/) a large list of cool plugin, i suggest you **duplicator**.)
3. When you are done, transfer the archive and the installer.php at the root of your localhost folder of wordpress and call localhost/your_wp_folder/installer.php
4. Follow the instructions from tutorial mentioned bellow.
5. Voila !

This is a tutorial to use Duplicator : [link here.](https://www.shoutmeloud.com/migrate-wordpress-server.html)

Comment: I tried to do this but the file size was too large for duplicator to use.

Comment: @AlwynOng Ah ok.. Did you try to upgrade your upload_max_filesize in php.ini (in wp-admin/php.ini) ? Set the var upload_max_filesize = 512M and retry

Comment: The duplicator plugin only allows for 500mb but the files on the website add up to >1 gb. Do you have any other options?

Comment: If you are a developer who are working recursively on WordPress, i advise you to buy the pro-version. You can either try wp-all-in-one migration, and also buy the pro version to bypass size limitation.

Comment: Also, you can do it manually : https://www.5balloons.info/migrate-setup-live-wordpress-site-localhost/

Comment: You obviously forget something. Did you reset your .htaccess ?

Comment: Yes, I tried resetting .htaccess but it still doesnt work